# Как определить наличие искомого объекта на изображении

Tags: c#, opencv

Есть код, с помощью которого я нахожу некоторый объект оранжевого цвета в определенной части экрана:

```
bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(700,347,0,0,size);

        imgWindowScreen = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmpScreenshot);

        imgWindowScreenProcessed = imgWindowScreen.InRange(new Bgr(3, 25, 82),      
                                         new Bgr(50, 98, 200));
```

Мне нужно продолжить работу в том случае, если на фрагменте находится объект нужного мне цвета. Вопрос - как я могу определить, что объект данного цвета на картинке есть?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно еще акутально.

Если вам просто нужно определить наличие определенного цвета на изображении, то вы двигаетесь в верном направлении. Накладываете фильтр, убирайте шум, анализируете количество белых пикселей в итоговом изображении - если превышает порог, который вы зададите, значит объект есть.

Другое дело если вам нужно искать определенный контур. Для кругов и прямоугольников в OpenCV есть методы. Для произвольной формы лучше будет использовать каскады Хаара например